# Multi module project : Which modules resources are used if not overwritten?

Tags: android, module, resources, android-resources

Let's say I have modules like following:

> - app-core
> - app-db
> - app-ui
> - app

The `app` module includes all 3 other modules. Let's say, all modules but `app` define a string with the name `app_name`. Which one does win? How can I control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources will be merged in this order:

> build variant > build type > product flavor > main source set > library dependencies

So when `app` is your apk those resources have highest priority,

> However, if your build configuration specifies multiple resource folders for a given source set and there are conflicts between those sources, an error occurs and the merge fails because each resource directory has the same priority.

full details are here:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources#resource_merging

Comment: `app` is my apk. It includes all other modules and all modules are *independent*. How is this case handled?

Comment: When you have the same resources in on the same level (i.e. with the same priority), the build should fail (see bottom of the linked docs)